# Configure Ubuntu hostnames

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, ubuntu-10.04, hostname

I'm trying to configure a Ubuntu 10.4 server and have a little confusion with configuring with hostnames.

My domain is `example.com` and the hostname would be `one`. If I'm correct, when I've configured this properly, typing `hostname` at the prompt would yield `one` and `hostname --fqdn` would yeild `one.example.com`. Am I right?

Could you tell me what values I would need to put in `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`?

Although a very trivial thing, I haven't been able to configure it to get the desirable output. I'm definitely missing something here.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In /etc/hostname you have to put the unqualified name for the host; in your example you need to put

```
one
```

In /etc/hosts, which is a DNS resolving file, you need to specify which IP address is host *one*. Let's suppose *one* has IP address 192.162.1.2, then you have to add this line to your /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.1.2 one.example.com one
```

(as stated on *man hosts*:  *IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]*).

Hope this helps

EDIT: I forgot: for Ubuntu AFAIK you have to run /etc/init.d/hostname.sh as root after modifying the hostname file. I'm not sure, but that's how it's done in Debian.

Comment: The init.d script likely just reads `/etc/hostname` and runs the `hostname` command.